# JQuery .click event is not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to link a click event to a dynamically loaded div, but the click event is not firing.

Code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(document).on('click', '.subMenuItem', function()
        {   
            alert('something'); 
                    });
                 });
```

I also have tried.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".subMenuItem").click(function()
        {   
            alert('something'); 
                    });
                 });
```

PHP:

```
<?php
/* Connects to the DB and grabs all SubMenuItems for the related Main Category */
require '/DBConnect.php';
$mainCategory = $_GET['MainCategory'];

$findSubCategories = mysqli_query($connection, 'SELECT DISTINCT Sub_Category FROM Product_Master WHERE Main_Category ="' . $mainCategory . '" ORDER BY Sub_Category');

while ($subCategories = mysqli_fetch_array($findSubCategories))
{
    $subCategory = $subCategories['Sub_Category'];
    echo '<div class="subMenuItem" id="' . $mainCategory . 'xx' . $subCategory . '">';
    echo $subCategory;
    echo '</div>';  
}
?>
```

AJAX that generates the SubMenuBar:

```
                    $.ajax({                                                          
                      url: '/php/SubMenuBar.php',         
                      data: {
                              MainCategory: mainCategory,
                            },

                      success: function(result) {
                          subMenuBar.html(result);  
                      }
                    });
```

The inspect element says there is an error on the final line of this script: (undefined is not a function):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".menuItem").click(function()
        {   
            var menuItemContent = $('#MenuItemContentWrapper');                                     
            var subMenuBar = $('#SubMenuBar');
            var mainCategory = $(this).attr('id').split('xx')[0];
            menuItemContent.slideUp(375);

            if ($(this).hasClass('active'))
            {
                subMenuBar.slideUp(375);
                $(this).css("background-image", "url(../PictureLibrary/NavBarShortcuts/" + this.id + ".gif)");
                $('.active').removeClass('active');
            }
            else
            {
                if (subMenuBar.hasClass('active'))
                {
                    subMenuBar.slideUp('fast', function(){ subMenuBar.slideDown(375); });
                }
                else
                {
                    subMenuBar.slideDown(375);
                }

                $.ajax({                                                          
                      url: '/php/SubMenuBar.php',         
                      data: {
                              MainCategory: mainCategory,
                            },

                      success: function(result) {
                          subMenuBar.html(result);  
                      }
                    });                 

                $(this).siblings().filter(".active")
                            .removeClass("active")
                            .each(function(i){
                                $(this).css("background-image", "url(../PictureLibrary/NavBarShortcuts/" + this.id + ".gif)");
                            });         

                $('.active').removeClass('active');                                         
                subMenuBar.addClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active').css( "background-image", "url(../PictureLibrary/NavBarShortcuts/" + this.id + "Active.gif)");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Your first example should work for a dynamically loaded element with the class subMenuItem. The second won't though.

Comment: Step 1. Paste your HTML. Step 2. Use `console.log()` and don't abuse `alert` like a debugging tool. Step 3. After step 1 and possibly 2, we can better address the issue. :D

Comment: @RUJordan My HTML is loaded dynamically using PHP and ajax, based on previous .click events (it dynamically inputs a subMenuBar based on the clicks with subMenuItems inside of it that are loaded from a DB)

Comment: @PugsOverDrugs it would still help to see how it's generated, and what you're doing on the other side of things.

Comment: @j08691 The first one is how other people solved the problem, but my alert will not fire.

Comment: Can you copy and paste some of the relevant markup?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2P2nK/ works for me.

Comment: When i use the .on() operator, do I need to have the $(document).ready(function(){ before it>?

Comment: @PugsOverDrugs No you don't need that.

Comment: As long as your script tag is in your body, not in your head, you don't need that.

Comment: @astex If script in the head you don't need that too. As long as you are delegating the descendants element with `document`

Comment: @RahilWazir You are correct.  My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. I updated the JQuery API that i was importing to the newest release on Google. Now the .on() method is working, sorry that it was something that I didn't think to include, but thanks for the help!!

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".subMenuItem").on('click',function() {
        alert("Clicked");
    });        
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D3etW/)

Comment: This doesn't make sense. This won't work with newly added elements.

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question.  Didn't read the comments.

Comment: So much for the 2 negatives. Apparently is did solve his problem as he clearly states.